# Opengl uniform behaviour

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I've noticed some things that aren't well explained in the opengl docs. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

1. You can't set the value of a uniform if the program isn't the one that opengl is using at that moment. That will generate an error.
2. If you set the value of a uniform in program A, then switch to program B, then switch back to program A, the value stays. Is this reliable?
3. There is no way to set a uniform value to a program that isn't being used at that moment. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. the [Direct State Access extension](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/direct_state_access.txt) (which is included in core 4.5) allows you to set the uniform to a non bound program using `glProgramUniform*EXT` and you will need to specify the program.
2. uniforms are stored per program,
3. see 1

Comment: By the way, `glProgramUniform*` is actually core in OpenGL 4.1 (it was introduced alongside `GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects`) and also available in older implementations that provide `GL_EXT_direct_state_access`.